# Calculate second and third high score

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a bit of code where we are passing variables from a Gravity Forms quiz in WP to a results table and are visually treating the high score differently from the rest of the answers.

I am having trouble trying to also calculate the second and third high scores, and also  pass those variables to the table to be displayed differently from the remaining answers.

Here is the high score code:

```
<?php

        $results = $_REQUEST['results'];

        $high_score = 0;

        // Find the highest score
        foreach ( $results as $result ) {
          if ( $result >= $high_score ) {
            $high_score = $result;
          }
         }
    ?>
```

and here is the code displaying the answers:

```
<?php 
            for ( $i = 0; $i < 9; $i++ ) {
                $type = $i + 1;

                if ( $results[$i] == $high_score ) {
                    echo '<td data-th="Type ' . $type . '" style="text-align: center; color: #42459c;"><strong>' . $results[$i] . '</strong></td>';
                } else {
                    echo '<td data-th="Type ' . $type . '" style="text-align: center; color: #3F4346;">' . $results[$i] . '</td>';
                }
            }
        ?>
```

How can I find the second and third highest scores?

Any help would be HUGE! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you? Sorting the results array from highest to lowest like this:

```
$results = $_REQUEST['results'];
rsort($results);
$results[0]; // Highest score
$results[1]; // Second highest score
$results[2]; // Third highest score
```

Display the results (if you only want 9):

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < 9; $i++ ) {
    if($i < count($results)){
        $type = $i + 1;
        if ( $i == 0 ) {
            echo '<td data-th="Type' . $type . '" style="text-align: center; color: #42459c;"><strong>' . $results[$i] . '</strong></td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td data-th="Type' . $type . '" style="text-align: center; color: #3F4346;">' . $results[$i] . '</td>';
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to explicitly say that 1st place is one color, 2nd place another color and so one, this could work:

```
foreach($results as $i => $result) {
    $type = $i+1;
    if($i == 0) // First
        echo '<td data-th="Type' . $type . '" style="text-align: center; color: red;"><strong>' . $result . '</strong></td>';
    else if($i == 1) // Second
        echo '<td data-th="Type' . $type . '" style="text-align: center; color: blue;"><strong>' . $result . '</strong></td>';
    else if($i == 2) // Third
        echo '<td data-th="Type' . $type . '" style="text-align: center; color: green;"><strong>' . $result . '</strong></td>';

    // All other results
    else
        echo '<td data-th="Type' . $type . '" style="text-align: center; color: gray;">' . $result . '</td>';
}
```

Comment: Be sure to check that there are at least 2 (3) results before making any use of the second (or third) entry.

Comment: No, unfortunately not (at least I don't think so)...the results categories are static (eg. Type1, Type 2, Type 3, Type 4, etc.) but the answers for each category are dynamic based on the user's input... so five different people could get 5 different results for Type 1 depending on how they answer...I need to visually differentiate the top 3 answers independent of where they show up...and plot twist I forgot to mention...there can also be the same result for the different types... So say there are 6 Categories and the results for the categories are 1,3,3,4,6,1. I need to bold the 3,3,4, and 6..

Comment: @kdruss I must admit, I don't quite follow what you need.

Comment: Sorry @bmla, Let me start at the beginning : ) There is a quiz with 36 questions, and each question has 2 choices. Each choice has a value of 1, and correlates to one of nine categories. So, for example, lets say a Question has choices that correlate to category 3 and category 5. if someone picks the first choice, it would add a tally of 1 to category 3. If they pick the second choice it would add a tally of 1 to category 5. (There are no right/wrong answers) At the end of the quiz we have a script that adds up each category's tally and displays the totals for each category in a table...

Comment: ...the code I posted finds the highest tally and **bolds** that value...what ever it is....I am trying to also bold the second and third highest values..

Comment: Your original question and code doesn't mention anything about categories, neither the fact that there seems to be a connections between a category and choice. Edit the question with the information you have provided in the comments. Possibly more code that shows what you have tried so far.

Comment: @kdruss see my third code block/example. It will bold the second and third highest values too.